# Can you identify the song from this video frame?

Tags: identify-this-song, music-video

Apple recently launched Apple Music, in their "home for music" video: https://youtu.be/Y1zs0uHHoSw they show the following music video frame: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qts9u.jpg

The video appears to show some sort of metallic cat-like creature emerging from a plane of liquid.

The videos don't allow comments and google image search has yielded nothing.

Not sure if this is the best place to ask, but I'm going crazy wanting to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song in question is *Pendulum by FKA twigs*.

The still image you referenced can be seen starting at 3m29s in the music video for this song.

Link: https://youtu.be/O8yix8PZKlw?t=209

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be consistent with the following:

The Weeknd - Can't Feel My Face

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEI4qSrkPAs

I will say that I am 100% sure it is from that music. It seems that the introduction was repeated over and over again. And some other elements of the music.

---

How I got there? Well, that's a funny story... A little. I found it by listening to this cover:

Can’t Feel My Face - The Weeknd (TeraBrite Pop Punk Cover Music Video)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbGv_5Vcbn8

I recommend both musics, with preferences to Terabrite.

Comment: Are you sure?   This album cover doesn't seem to look anything like the single cover or the album cover.   It doesn't seems to appear in the music video either.

Comment: @JacobSwanson It isn't a cover, but the background sound. At first, it sounded like a loop but it seems like it is the full background. That is, the original music without the singer's voice.

Comment: A few album covers show, it doesn't mean it is linked to that one cover.  And they could just be using the background because it was/is popular and easily recognized.

Comment: @JacobSwanson It's not a cover...